# Retrieve property value from array of object

Tags: php, arrays, object, symfony, properties

I know the problem is simple, but I can't find how to resolve it. I need to retrieve a value from a variable, but in vain:

I have the following controller:

```
  public function followersAction()
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $usr= $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

            $query = $em->createQuery(
                    'SELECT p
                    FROM TESTBlogBundle:Follow p               
                    WHERE p.followed = :me'
                    )->setParameter('me', $usr->getId());
                    $followers = $query->getResult();

            return array(
                'entities' => $followers
            );
        }
```

Inside another controller, I am using:

```
$myfollowers=$this->followersAction();
```

when I var_dump, I have:

```
array(3) {
  ["entities"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(TEST\Bundle\BlogBundle\Entity\Follow)#364 (3) {
      ["id":"TEST\Bundle\BlogBundle\Entity\Follow":private]=>
      int(1)
      ["follower"]=>
      int(2)
      ["followed"]=>
      int(1)
    }
  }
  ["current_user"]=>
  int(1)
  ["followers_count"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

I need to get the value of property :follower.

```
foreach($myfollowers as $myfollower)
    {
        echo '<pre>';

        var_dump($myfollower[0]->follower);
        var_dump($myfollower[0]->getFollower());
        var_dump($myfollower->getFollower());

        echo '</pre>';


    }
```

I am getting errors like: Trying to get property of non-object, Call to a member function getFollower() on a non-object.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to loop through the wrong scope. $myfollowers['entities'] contains the right ones, so you could use this as a starting point for your loop.

The following should do the trick.

```
foreach($myfollowers['entities'] as $myfollower)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($myfollower->getFollower());
    echo '</pre>';    
}
```